# Load Unity html game inside iOS UIWebView

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I developed a simple game using unity, then I exported it (build it) to html game .. so now I have: Build folder + index.html + Template folder. 
Can I import these files into a new xcode project and load index.html in a UIwebview in iOS ? I tired this but it didn't work, is there a way to do this ?

Comment: I think it's not good idea - run game in `UIWebView`. Unity is a crossplatform game engine and you can build your game to iOS target. I'm not Unity expert, but I think [this article](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/building-your-unity-game-ios-device-testing) will help you.

Comment: You are right, but I want many games run inside my app , basically my app has a section fore games. 

Thanks for help